# JSF / PrimeFaces Validation Hangs

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

JSF/PrimeFaces Validation Problem.

Primefaces validation of inputText fields leaves IE and Firefox browsers in busy cursor mode.

FacesMessage validation message is properly displayed on the page, but busy cursor continues.
Page reload is required to stop the busy cursor.

FireFox Firebug does not indicate a bug.  IE browser indicates a jquery error.

If there is indeed a javascript error, then that would stop all ajax processing.

Phases reported:

START RESTORE_VIEW
END RESTORE_VIEW

START APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES
END APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES

START PROCESS_VALIDATIONS
END PROCESS_VALIDATIONS

START RENDER_RESPONSE
END RENDER_RESPONSE

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: The JS error is the cause of the "infinite loading". As long as you don't elaborate about the JS error in detail, nor posts the problem in flavor of an SSCCE, it's hard to help you solving it. The JSF phase logging at least suggests that there's an input conversion/validation error. But that's likely not directly related to the JS error.

Comment: BalusC: thanks for reply.  I did a lot of research before posting, and added the PhaseListener based on some of your debugging articles.  I didn't post the page code because it's very long.  I will follow your pointer about a suggested input conversion/validation error.

Comment: The solution to this problem was to remove duplicate PrimeFaces jars.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883077/jsf-error-message-and-program-stuck-json-parsing-error-and-primefaces/17959951#17959951

Comment: As long as you never share the exact error in the question, no one would be able to post a reliable answer. In future questions, always always post the full error and don't ignore it as if it's irrelevant decoration.